# Using regular expressions to match log file

Tags: regex

I am working on a regular expression problem and have run into some issues when I try to match text between certain markers. Below is a regular expression tester with what I have completed so far.

https://regex101.com/r/gE8uQ1/1

I am trying to select the ALL of the query text which appears after "statement: " and before the \nTIMESTAMP. I have used \n\d{4}-d{2}-d{2} to represent the timestamp, but it will not select the whole query. Why is this happening? Is it because of my modifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=statement: )([ _\-|0-9,:;\.=A-Za-z\(\)"\n\t']+?)(?=(?:\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$))
```

Try this.See demo.Just change your `negative lookahead` to `positive lookahead` and add `quantifier` to `character class`.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gE8uQ1/5

Comment: you missed a `$` at the end :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following with `g` and `s` (because your querys have new lines which are not matched by `.`) modifiers:

```
(?<=statement: )([ _\-|0-9,:;\.=A-Za-z\(\)"\n\t'].+?)(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$)
                                                   ^   ^                  ^
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gE8uQ1/3)